# How can I use rotateY attribute in Android older than 3.0?

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

I want to use `rotateY=180` attribute in Android older than 3.0. How should I override `onDraw` method in my custom view to create this behavior of attributes? In the Android greater than 3.0 there is no problem with it but in older one this is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) 
{
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(angle * 180.0f / (float) Math.PI);



canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: Where should I call `super.onDraw(canvas)` and other question is what angle value should be if I want to be rotateY = 180 ?

Comment: You do not call onDraw(), it is called automatically. You can call invalidte(), where you want to rotate view.

Comment: I want to create a custom button that rotate in Y axis with value 180.

Comment: I want exactly to add behavior rotateY = 180 attribute